# How to use selected value from table and use it for next selection from another table in one query?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables,for example:

```
table_1 (id_t1,id_t2,...);

table_2 (id_t2,...);
```

I know **id_t1** of the **table_1** and I need to get all rows from **table_1** by the value of **id_t2** with a join table 2. Can I do it for one query at MariaDB?

Now I can do this:

```sql
select id_t2 from table_1;

select * 
from table_1 left join table_2 on table_1.id_t2=table_2.id_t2 
where id_t2=the result of past query;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a `IN` statement

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id_t2=table_2.id_t2 
WHERE table1.id_t2 IN (select tAux.id_t2 from table_1 as tAux);
```

Comment: @Eribiel Thank you mate your idea is fine but it throwed me an error the id_t2 in All,IN,ANY subquery is ambiguous. Then I rectified this query like that:SELECT * 
FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id_t2=table_2.id_t2 
WHERE table_1.id_t2 IN (select id_t2 from table_1 where id_t1=my own value);

Comment: i think this was more related to the fact that i used id_t2, let me edit my answer. Now with the aliases should work right... i think what you changed will give you something else, but hell if its not broken don't fix it, thanks dimitri

Comment: yes it didn't work because of id_t2. I will try with aliases tomorrow now

Comment: The query with aliases shows me all rows where id_t2 is equally for other rows  but how I wrote above I was needed to select all rows from table_1 by id_t1. Anyway you helped me man, now I got what I need!

Comment: Yeah, i was just pointing out why it was failing. Glad to be helpful!